# Relation of range of an operator and its adjoint operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Suppose that the operator $\mathcal A: H\to H$ (H: Hilbert space) is closed, densely defined and have closed range. Then $H=R(\mathcal A) \oplus N(\mathcal A^*)$, $\mathcal A^*$ is the adjoint of $\mathcal A$.

1. So for all $q\in D(\mathcal A^*)\subset H$, we may write $q=q_1+q_2$, where $q_1\in R(\mathcal A)$ and $q_2\in N(\mathcal A^*)$. Can we show that $q_1=(\mathcal A^*)^{-1}q$?
2. Why can we assert that there are $x\in R(\mathcal A^*)$ and $y\in R(\mathcal A)$ such that $Ax=y$?

Comment: If $\mathcal{N}(\mathcal{A}^*)$ is non-zero, then $(\mathcal{A}^*)^{-1}$ does not exist.

Comment: I think that $(\mathcal A^*)^{-1}: R(\mathcal A^*)\to D(\mathcal A^*)$, so it exists.

Comment: A linear operator with a non-trivial null space is not invertible.